# Is there an easy way to find what is wrong

Tags: r, shiny

I am getting  the "attempt to apply non-function" error on the blow code, but can't find the syntax error. Can anyone else see the problem? Much appreciated.

```
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    br(),
    
    # TASK 1: Application title
    titlePanel(title = "Trends in Demographics and Income"),
    p("Explore the difference between people who earn less than 50K and more than 50K. You can filter the data by country, then explore various demogrphic information."),
    
    # TASK 2: Add first fluidRow to select input for country
    fluidRow(
      column(12, 
             wellPanel(varSelectInput("country",
                                      "Country of Origin",
                                      data = adult, 
                                      selected = "United-States"))  # add select input 
             )),
    
    # TASK 3: Add second fluidRow to control how to plot the continuous variables
    fluidRow(
      column(3, 
             wellPanel(
               p("Select a continuous variable and graph type (histogram or boxplot) to view on the right."),
               radioButtons("continuous_variable",
                            label = "Age or Hrs/wk",
                            choices = c("age", "hour_per_week"),
                            selected = "age"),                  # add radio buttons for continuous variables
               radioButtons("graph_type",
                            label = "Histogram or Boxplot",
                            choices = c("histogram", "boxplot"),
                            selected = "histogram")             # add radio buttons for chart type
               )),
      column(9, plotOutput("p1"))  # add plot output
            ),
    
    # TASK 4: Add third fluidRow to control how to plot the categorical variables
    fluidRow(
      column(3, 
             wellPanel(
               p("Select a categorical variable to view bar chart on the right. Use the check box to view a stacked bar chart to combine the income levels into one graph. "),
               radioButtons("categorical_variable",
                            "Categorical Variables",
                            choices = c("Education","Workclass","Sex"),
                            selected = "Education"),    # add radio buttons for categorical variables
               checkboxInput("is_stacked",
                             label = "Stacked",
                             value = FALSE)     # add check box input for stacked bar chart option
               )
             ),
      column(9, plotOutput("p2"))  # add plot output
    )
  )
)
```

I am working on this project as a final for a programming course I am taking, but I can't check my work with this error popping up. If someone could please look over what I've got so far, I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Your code is not a minimal reproducible example.  You've provided us with the UI, but not the server function, nor the final call to run the app nor at least one dataset (`adult`).  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help you construct a *minimal reproducible example*.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: Worth adding that minimal reproducible examples aren't just good on SO--it is a fundamental debugging technique, and is perhaps the best general answer to *"Is there an easy way to find what is wrong."*

Comment: But also, after you get the error, run `traceback()` and see if you can tell what line of your code gets to the error.

Comment: I've tried your code here replacing `adult` with `letters` (vector), `1:10` (int), `rnorm(10)` (floating point), `mtcars`, `tibble(mtcars)`, even something nonsensical like `data=mean`, and they all produce valid-looking HTML. I then stop using `shinyUI` (since it is superseded), I tried it with `shinyApp(ui=..., server=function(input,output){})` with the same wrong-data, and nothing broke. My guess is that your `attempt to apply non-function` is in your `server=` code, not the `ui=` code.

Comment: Thanks for the help, definitely new to this, sorry that my question wasn't super helpful. The lab is telling me it should create an empty html page with some formatting if I remove all the unfinished server code. I guess I'll just try to finish everything and see it that fixes the problem.